# displaying data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Having a little trouble displaying data from a table. Been looking at my code for the past few hours and can't seem to see the problem. What I am trying to do is when a team is clicked on it will go into the players table and display any player that has that team name on the team page. I keep getting a blank page:

**index.php**

This is the case that launches the team_view.php

```
case 'view_team':

        $team = $_GET['name'];
        $teams = get_players_by_team($team);
        include('team_view.php');
        break;
```

**team_view.php**

```
<?php include '../../view/header.php'; ?>
<?php include '../../view/sidebar_admin.php'; ?>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Team Roster</h1>

    <!-- display product -->
    <?php include '../../view/team.php'; ?>

    <!-- display buttons -->

</div>
<?php include '../../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

**team.php**

```
<?php

    $team = $team['name'];  
    $first = $player['first'];
    $last = $player['last'];
    $age = $player['age'];
    $position = $player['position'];
    $team = $player['team'];

?>

<table>
    <?php foreach ($players as $player) :

    ?>
        <tr>

            <td id="product_image_column" >
                <img src="images/<?php echo $player['player_id']; ?>_s.png"
                     alt="&nbsp;">
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <a href="?action=view_player&amp;player_id=<?php echo
                           $player['player_id']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $player['first']; ?>
                        <?php echo $player['last']; ?>
                    </a>
                </p>

            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

**product_db.php**

```
<?php
function get_players_by_team($team) {
   global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM players
              WHERE team = :team';
    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':team', $team);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetch();
        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        display_db_error($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: see what `get_players_by_team` function returns using var_dump or print_r 
and please post it :)

Comment: What's in your web server error logs? A blank screen generally means that there's a problemw it the PHP syntax.

Comment: Please consider adding a comment why did you down vote this

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a data base, its a data base management script.

Comment: error that I am getting is " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Answer (score 0):

You never define `$players` it looks like what you are expecting to be `$players` is actually `$teams`.

```
$teams = get_players_by_team($team);
```

Additionally youre using `$player` at the top of the script instead of inside the loop which makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to php, just trying to figure this out... so would I use players as the variable name: $players = get_players_by_team($team);

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at top of page to view all errors.

Comment: error that I am getting is " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Yes, that error is because you are trying to loop over something that isnt iterable, or in this case is undefined. Changing `$teams` to `$players` or vice versa should fix that particular issue.